# React Application with Cache Control for images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, cache-control

I don't know how to use cache control for my React application, can someone help me? When I set it up in Nginx, the images don't load, I understand that is because when I build my static assets are renamed. So can someone give me a solution that I can use for this?

If this helps, here is the the website, you can run Light House https://longislandbrainandspine.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache-control headers need to be defined in the server config. You can set a regex-based query path for all static assets like this

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    root /folder_where_your_assets_are;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

This should likely be under the server level config.

Comment: Ok, but when I do that, the images won't load, I mean, the images from the rest API work, but not the one from the static server. I'm loading images from two resources, for the core pages they are in the static folder generated by React when I build, but for dynamic, I'm pulling images from WP Rest API

Comment: What error/code do you get for those images? Make sure your root folder path is set correctly. It needs to be the absolute path of the static resources.